# Error while pasting object from Clipboard

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, clipboard

This is my code for copying and pasting an object to the clipboard:

```
private void CopyObject()
{
    Clipboard.SetData(ClipboardDataFormats.SampleData, this.SelectedSampleObject);
}

private void PasteObject()
{
    if (Clipboard.ContainsData(ClipboardDataFormats.SampleData) == true)
    {
        var sampleObject = (SampleClass)Clipboard.GetData(ClipboardDataFormats.SampleData); // exception
    }
}
```

I receive following exception when I call [`Clipboard.GetData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdata.aspx)

> **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException** Data on clipboard is invalid.
>
> **HRESULT** 0x800401D3 (CLIPBRD_E_BAD_DATA)

Maybe the reason for the error is that `SelectedSampleObject` is an entity framework proxy object, when calling [`Clipboard.SetData()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.setdata.aspx). Is this possible? Do you have any other idea? Unfortunately i really don't understand this exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about this specific exception, but your code will not work with EF proxy objects anyway, because objects you put to clipboard must be serializable (for example marked with `Serializable` attribute), and EF proxy classes are not. You can of course disable proxy creation and mark all your entity classes with `[Serialiable]` but I doubt you want to do this. Instead, create some another class with only required properties, mark it with Serialiable and use that for clipboard operations. Or serialize your object to json\xml whatever yourself and set that to clipboard.

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll give it a try!

Comment: "Instead, create some another class with only required properties, mark it with Serialiable" that's useful, especially if you don't have full control over the inheritance tree (normally you'd have to mark as serializable all classes up to the base one, which might be e.g. part of the .NET Framework)